# Stalk of inverse image sheaf

Tags: sheaf-theory

I am trying to learn algebraic geometry from Hartshorne's book.  I have a question regarding the stalk of the restricted sheaf. Let $X$ be a topological space and $Z$ a subspace of $X$. Consider the inclusion map $Z \hookrightarrow X$. Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a sheaf on $X$. Let $P$ be a point in $Z$. At the end of the first section in the second chapter, it is mentioned that the stalk of the restricted sheaf $\mathcal{F} \mid_{Z}$ at $P$ is equal (isomorphic) to the stalk of $\mathcal{F}$ at $P$. I tried to prove this statement from the definition of stalk and eventually ended up with direct limit of direct limits. Is there a better way to see this statement using the results of the first section?

Comment: I think the best way to prove this statement is to note that the stalk functor $\mathcal{F}\mapsto\mathcal{F}_P$ is actually the inverse image functor along the inclusion $i_P:\{P\}\hookrightarrow X$, in other words $\mathcal{F}_P\simeq i_P^{-1}\mathcal{F}$ (using the identification that sheaves on a one point topological space is just a set). Now if $i:Z\hookrightarrow X$ is any inclusion (or any map btw), then $(\mathcal{F}|_Z)_P=i_P^{-1}i^{-1}\mathcal{F}=(i\circ i_P)^{-1}\mathcal{F}=\mathcal{F}_P$.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.